# Multipeer Connectivity Can Not Connect

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to connect an iPhone device and the iPhone simulator using the Multipeer Connectivity framework.

So far, I've tried the code in [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/), and [this one](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/) too, but I haven't been able to connect the two devices successfully:

1. Sometimes, one of the devices does not appear in the other device's browser list (`MCBrowserViewController`).
2. Other times, one of the devices appears TWICE or THREE TIMES in the other device's browser ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235487/ios-multi-peer-connectivity-showing-same-device-name-twice)'s answer does not solve this issue). Restarting/Deleting the app does not fix it, but changing the "service type" string does. Somehow the sessions "stay alive"?
3. If I advertise using an instance of `MCAdvertiserAssistant`, the invitation dialog simply is not shown on the target device.
4. If, instead, I use an instance of `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` plus an alert view, I do get the invitations but accepting them causes the state to hang in "Connecting", and the "Done" button of the browser never becomes enabled (this is the farthest I have come).
5. I've read several questions/answers here, and it still isn't clear if I should use the same or different sessions for browsing/advertising, and what lifetime said sessions should have.

Note: The real device is running iOS 8 beta.

Comment: I'm having the same problems on iOS 8.1...

Comment: Sorry, I was coding a prototype for a project that got cancelled. Never found the answer on my own. Anyone with knowledge is welcome to chime in...

Comment: @NicolasMiari Have you found the solution?

Comment: @SaurabhJain like I said, it was just a prototype, it got cancelled and I moved on. Haven't really had time to look into it again.